# How to prepend spaces in LINQ to Entities queries

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In linq-to-entities queries, how spaces be prepended to shorter-length values when querying against an nvarchar column?

I seek this capability to facilitate proper sorting of certain fields.

**Here is my scenario**:

I have database that contains *part number* columns in virtually every table.  These part number columns are represented as nvarchar(20) in the database.  They usually contain a combination of both 6-digit and 8-digit part numbers.  The vast majority of these part "numbers" are in fact numeric; but some are non-numeric. Consequently they are represented as strings rather than integers.

Because these part numbers are represented as strings rather than numbers, they do no sort properly.  The 6-digit and 8-digit values are intermingled rather than separately grouped.  So I want to pad the shorter length values with leading spaces to solve the sorting problem.

I do realize that if these columns were stored as *nchar* rather than *nvarchar*, I would get this padding automatically.  But changing the data type for these columns is not an option at this point.

When I craft my own linq queries, I can do sorting properly:

```
db.table.Select(_ => _.partNumberColumn).OrderBy(_ => _.Length).ThenBy(_ => _);
```

The problem arises when other tools (such as grid) automatically compose queries.  Then don't know about the additional sorting requirements.  So it seems like a good solution is to prepend the spaces to the values that are of shorter length.

Here's an example query.  When I build the model, rather than merely bringing in the values, I want to prepend 2 spaces to the 6-character values.

```
_db.HubAssembliesWides
    .Select(_ =>
        new Models.HubAssemblyModel()
        {
            HubAssemblyNumber = _.HubAssemblyNumber,
            DetailedOnNumber = _.DetailedOnNumber,
            HubMachiningNumber = _.HubMachiningNumber,
            HubCastingNumber = _.HubCastingNumber,
            ComponentHubAssemblyNumber = _.ComponentHubAssemblyNumber
        }
    );
```

So instead of

```
HubAssemblyNumber = _.HubAssemblyNumber
```

I want

```
HubAssemblyNumber = _.HubAssemblyNumber.Length == 6 ? "  " + _.HubAssemblyNumber : _.HubAssemblyNumber
```

Can this be done?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Surprise!  I didn't realize that the syntax that I proposed actually works.

```
HubAssemblyNumber = _.HubAssemblyNumber.Length == 6 ? "  " + _.HubAssemblyNumber : _.HubAssemblyNumber
```

Gets translated into a ***case*** statement when translated by linq-to-entities into T-SQL.